# Render 404 page if the user has entered the wrong URL and is not authenticated in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, routes, next.js

Please refer to the code below:

*Auth.tsx*

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext, FC } from 'react';

interface Props {
  // any props that come into the component
}

export const PUBLIC_ROUTES = ['/', '/admin/login'];

export const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';

const AuthContext = createContext({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: false,
  user: {},
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthProvider: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUserFromCookies() {
      // const token = Cookies.get('token');
      // TODO: Get the token from the cookie
      const token = true;

      if (token) {
        // console.log("Got a token in the cookies, let's see if it is valid");
        // api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        // const { data: user } = await api.get('users/me');
        // if (user) setUser(user);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    }

    loadUserFromCookies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ isAuthenticated: !!Object.keys(user).length, user, isLoading }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const ProtectRoute: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }

  if (PUBLIC_ROUTES.includes(window.location.pathname)) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  // If the user is not on the browser or not authenticated
  if (!isBrowser() || !isAuthenticated) {
    window.location.replace('/login');
    return null;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

*_app.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { AppProps } from 'next/dist/next-server/lib/router/router';
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../utils/theme';
import { AuthProvider, ProtectRoute } from 'contexts/auth';

export default function MyApp(props: AppProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');

    if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentElement) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Next App</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
        />
      </Head>

      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <AuthProvider>
            <ProtectRoute>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ProtectRoute>
          </AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

### Problems:

1. So, as per the code, if the user is not logged in, redirect the user
   to the login page. But, due to the current logic, 404-page
   routes are also redirected to the admin login page. How can I catch
   the 404 status to redirect to the 404 pages before verifying if the
   user is logged in or not?
2. I am using an array to verify if the path is public or not. Is there
   a better way to render public paths without maintaining hard-coded
   page paths or using HOCs? The issue with my approach is if any developer changes the file name and if it doesn't match the string in the array, it will not be a public route. If I create a folder called public and all public pages inside it, I get an unnecessary `public/` in my URL. I do not want to use HOCs because I have to import them every time I create a new page which isn't incorrect but I am expecting a better approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

2. You can use HOC (Higher Order Components) to wrap the paths which:

- can only accessed with authorization;
- can only be access when
  user unauthenticated (e.g `/login` -> you don't want user to
  access `/login` page when he's already logged in)

Like so:

`login.js` -> `/login`

```
import withoutAuth from 'path/withoutAuth';

function Login() {
  return (<>YOUR COMPONENT</>);
};

export default withoutAuth(Login);
```

Same can be done with `withAuth.js` -> HOC (Higher Order Component) which wraps components which can only accessed with authentication

`protectedPage.js` -> `/protectedPage`

```
import withAuth from 'path/withAuth';

function ProtectedPage() {
  return (<>YOUR COMPONENT</>);
};

export default withAuth(ProtectedPage);
```

You can how you can make these HOCs in this article.

1. Setting up authentication and `withConditionalRedirect`  (HOC which will be used to make `withAuth` & `withoutAuth` HOCs): [Detecting Authentication Client-Side in Next.js with an HttpOnly Cookie When Using SSR](https://dev.to/justincy/detecting-authentication-client-side-in-next-js-with-an-httponly-cookie-when-using-ssr-4d3e).
2. Making `withAuth` & `withoutAuth` HOCs: [Detecting a User's Authenticated State Client-Side in Next.js using an HttpOnly Cookie and Static Optimization](https://dev.to/justincy/detecting-a-user-s-authenticated-state-client-side-in-next-js-using-an-httponly-cookie-and-static-optimization-6ib)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this approach in various blog posts. But, my only issue with this approach is that we have to use that HOC whenever I create a new page. I would rather have everything related to routes in one place than using the HOC for every page. I do not see anything wrong with your solution but maybe I am expecting something for cleaner and organized. I don't even consider my approach (array of public routes) cleaner.